# How to get out the stored data from Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not getting the output from Firebase database. It's not returning anything. Here is my data structure.

I also tried getting value through query but it returned database error:

> Cannot convert java.util.hashmap to String

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Member").push();

myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

              String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
              Log.d("Tag", "Value is" + value);
          }
      }
```

JSON:

```
{
  "Member" : {
    "-LhKJVG1Tj2628sHPg4D" : {
      "age" : "21",
      "name" : "Gagan",
      "nickname" : "Gaggi"`enter code here`
    },
    "-LhKKaNFnPrrh1bQNPfH" : {
      "age" : "18",
      "name" : "Jashan",
      "nickname" : "Jassi"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share the database structure

Comment: i 'm a new contributor. So, can't share images. My database Structure consists name,age,nickname under child(id provided by firebase) under Member.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: check it now, i posted Json file of Database Structure also.

Comment: That's not how you read data from Firebase, push() is out of place. There are other issues as well but you have to get that part correct to start with. See the Firebase Documentation [Filtering Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data). You should read over the entire guide but the example in the Filtering section is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call getValue with String.class because it does not meet the criteria of the method call.

From the documentation

public  T getValue(Class valueType)

This method is used to marshall the data contained in this snapshot into a class of your choosing. The class must fit 2 simple constraints:
The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized
An example class might look like:

```
 class Message {
     private String author;
     private String text;

     private Message() {}

     public Message(String author, String text) {
         this.author = author;
         this.text = text;
     }

     public String getAuthor() {
         return author;
     }

     public String getText() {
         return text;
     }
 }


 // Later
 Message m = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **String** class

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String name= ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        String age= ds.child("age").getValue(String.class);
        //and similar for others
        Log.d("TAG", email + " / " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: On a child yes, but not directly like the OP is doing.